# How to Monitor When an Application Closes?

Tags: linux

I'd like to monitor my Atom text editor so I can run a script when it closes.

I would like to open the editor using the command line syntax `atom`. When I close the editor, I'd like it to trigger a bash script.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean an already running instance of the editor? or maybe an instance invoked in an arbitrary way? If you mean `atom` yet to be run then `atom; whatever`. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure this basic shell syntax is what you want.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I can be more clear, but I've edited the question. I don't understand what you mean by an "already running instance" versus an "instance involved in an arbitrary way."

Comment: For the record: "already running instance" is `atom` you have invoked without any preparation whatsoever and now you want to monitor it; as opposed to `atom` invoked in a special way that easily allows you to monitor it but requires some actions beforehand. "Invoked in an arbitrary way" means from a shell, from a desktop shortcut or an icon wherever, from cron (if possible), `at`, task spooler or in whatever way which may or *may not* involve typing `atom`. // The edit was helpful. Now it looks like you want a wrapper function or a wrapper script, setting it up is an "action beforehand".

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to open the editor using the command line syntax `atom`. When I close the editor, I'd like it to trigger a bash script.

Create a shell function or a script that runs the real `atom` and then `whatever` you want to run next.

---

#### Example function

```bsh
atom () (
  command atom "$@"
  /path/to/whatever
)
```

Define the function in the right startup file (`~/.bashrc` for Bash). Open a new shell. From now on `atom` invoked from the shell should run the function. This method won't work outside of the shell.

---

#### Example script

(Note: there is no point in using the function and the script together.)

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/real/atom "$@"
/path/to/whatever
```

Name the script `atom`, make it executable and place it in a directory that is earlier in your `PATH` than the directory with any other `atom` (you may need to create such directory and modify your `PATH`). Now anything that uses the `PATH` variable to locate `atom` will find the script. This method can work outside of the shell.

However if anything tries to run Atom by its usual path (i.e. not via `PATH`) then it will run the real `atom` like the script does. You can move the real `atom` to elsewhere, place the script where everyone expects the real `atom` (and adjust `/path/to/real/atom` in the script so the script does not call itself); but I don't recommend this because an attempt to update Atom will most likely overwrite the script.

---

#### Possible improvements

- The above function or the above script exits with the exit status of `whatever` because it's the last command. Maybe you want it to exit with the exit status of the real `atom`. This is especially reasonable in case of the script. The script under the name `atom` may be called by anything that wants to run the real `atom` and we cannot rule out that some calling process uses the exit status of `atom` for something.

  A function that preserves the exit status is like this:

  ```bsh
  atom () (
     command atom "$@"
     status="$?"
     /path/to/whatever
     exit "$status"
  )
  ```

  (Function deliberately in a subshell, so its `status` variable does not affect the main shell.)

  Similarly the script:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/sh
  /path/to/real/atom "$@"
  status="$?"
  /path/to/whatever
  exit "$status"
  ```
- You may want the function or the script to exit as soon as possible after the real `atom` exits, you may want `whatever` to start asynchronously. Make the function/script run `/path/to/whatever &` instead of `/path/to/whatever` then.

---

#### General notes

- Our function or our script runs `whatever` after *trying* to run the real `atom`. Neither it matters if the real `atom` displays a window nor if it starts at all. By testing the exit status you can detect some abnormalities (e.g. if `/path/to/real/atom` triggers `No such file or directory` then the exit status is `127`) and conditionally suppress `whatever`. If by "when an application closes" you mean "when its window closes" then it's not that simple.
- In general a program like a browser or a text editor, if invoked for the second time, may detect another instance already running and delegate its own task to the other process. In effect e.g. a new tab or something is created in the old window. The new process exits just after handing the task over; the task becomes responsibility of the old instance. If Atom does this then you will observe `whatever` (associated with the new process) running just after the new process delegates the task and exits, even if the task itself is far from being completed/closed. I don't know Atom, I don't know if it works this way.
- In general a process may call its own executable or its name to spawn another instance (possibly silent and without any window). If Atom (i.e. the real `atom`) ever does this in a way that uses `PATH` to locate `atom` and if it finds the script then you will observe more instances of `whatever` than you expect. There are methods that don't use `PATH`. Again: I don't know Atom, I don't know if it ever does this nor in what way.

Comment: Thank you for writing such a thorough answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as I was hoping. I've tried using the commands in both my `~/bin` directory as a stand-alone script and in my `~/.functions` file as a function. When I run `command atom "$@"`, Atom opens as expected, `/path/to/whatever` runs immediately, and `exit` closes the terminal. What I'm looking for is to run `/path/to/whatever` only after Atom is closed.